# How do I create a dependency free dll from an old C# Solution?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dependencies, .net-assembly

I got hold of a project that I need to do a thing that I've never worked before.

I have an old Solution that has very bad design patterns. So to improve the Solution and make it more modular, I need to remove one of the folders called Remote Services and make a dll out of it to be used in other future solutions if needed, removing any adjacent dependecies to the old Solution. This Remote Services are used for you to be able to connect from a specific App and a PC software to some measuring instruments with the objective to export and import data.

This Remove Services are divided in two projects, the Interfaces and Implementation. In the Interfaces I have the necessary interfaces, enums and dtos that I need. From the Implementation I would "just need" to look to the old Solution and copy classes and methods and organize it better. But then, I got to the problem that quite a few classes and methods from the Remote Services uses other interfaces, methods and types from other folders/projects on the old Solution.

So, the main question is that. How do I create an independent dll with the same methods as on the old Solution but removing this dependencies and references to other projects? Every time I see a dependency to other class outside Remote Services, should I create an interface on my dll or something? I really don't know.

If someone could give me tips how to organize this would be very appreciated. I can put later a screenshot of the old Solution and the solution of my dll.

Comment: It's hard to say something without concrete examples. Ideally you have no circular dependencies at all in your solution. Whenever ProjectA references ProjectB there should be no reference from ProjectB back to ProjectA. Example: Your BusinessLogic project should reference the DataAccess project, but not the other way around. But this can be a major refactoring. A quick and dirty solution would be to create a project with all interfaces that is referenced from the other projects.

Comment: Hello, thank your for you answer.

For example, in my old Solution I have folders like:
a) Application
b) Presentation
c) Common
d) Remote Services
....

And like I said, on Remote Services I have classes with methods that have dependencies to other folders, for example, I need a class from the Common folder that needs to calculate some value that I need to send on my Remote Services. But since now the Remote Services is my dll, and on that solution I don't have the Common folder, I have a dependecie missing on the dll. But I can't have dependencies to the old Solution.

Comment: So, how I am I supposed to have the same method on my dll like on the old Solution but without the dependencies.? Some classes or interfaces I really need are supposed to be calculated/asserted on other places outside the Remote Services. But I really need to get the values/classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. Basically, the trick, was doing by dependency injection.